# Non object in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am working on my laravel project but i am having some issues with it and getting the error "Trying to get property 'game_id' of non-object"

I am new to laravel and i kinda need some help and or advice thanks.

Code:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Config;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\DispatchesJobs;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller as BaseController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Validation\ValidatesRequests;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\AuthorizesRequests;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
use Auth;

class Controller extends BaseController
{
    use AuthorizesRequests, DispatchesJobs, ValidatesRequests;

    protected $user;
    protected $redis;
    protected $config;
 
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->redis = Redis::connection();
        $this->config = Config::find(1);
 
        $settings = (object) [
            'appId' => $this->config->game_id,
            'domain' => $this->config->domain,
            'sitename' => $this->config->sitename,
            'title' => $this->config->title,
            'description' => $this->config->description,
            'keywords' => $this->config->keywords,
            'vk_group' => $this->config->vk_group,
            'support_email' => $this->config->support_email,
            'site_name_protocol' => $this->config->site_name_protocol,
            'free' => $this->config->bonus_free
        ];
 
        view()->share('settings', $settings);
 
        $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
            $this->user = Auth::user();
```

My app\config:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Config extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'domain', 'sitename', 'title', 'description', 'keywords',
        'game_id', 'bot_steamid', 'bot_key', 'bot_username', 'bot_password', 'bot_shared_secret', 'bot_identity_secret',
        'vk_group', 'support_email', 'site_name_protocol',
        'payment',
        'freekassa_id', 'freekassa_secret1', 'freekassa_secret2',
        'unitpay_public', 'unitpay_secret',
        'bonus_free'
    ];
}
```

Screenshot:
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsXfh.png)

Comment: `$this->config` doesn't contain what you think it does. `var_dump()` it to verify.

Comment: How do i var dump it? Put it above $settings? and then run php artisian?

Comment: I var dumped, then die() and it says "NULL" (i used: var_dump($this->config);)

Comment: _'and it says "NULL"'_ That's exactly what I was getting at. :) I.e., the lookup failed. Don't assume you're going to get a valid value back.

Comment: `(null)->game_id` is not valid. Do you have a record in your `configs` table with an ID of 1? Currently, you code is failing at `$this->config = Config::find(1);`, and is returning `null`.

Comment: Then what is the issue? I'm not a laravel guru :/

Comment: _"Then what is the issue?_" The lookup failed. There is no config record with ID 1. (Or the `find` failed for some other reason, like bad user/pass on the database.)

Answer (score 0):

you need to check whether $this->config is null or not.

```
$this->config = Config::find(1);

if($this->config){

 $settings = (object) [

        'appId' => $this->config->game_id,
        'domain' => $this->config->domain,
        'sitename' => $this->config->sitename,
        'title' => $this->config->title,
        'description' => $this->config->description,
        'keywords' => $this->config->keywords,
        'vk_group' => $this->config->vk_group,
        'support_email' => $this->config->support_email,
        'site_name_protocol' => $this->config->site_name_protocol,
        'free' => $this->config->bonus_free

      ];

}
```

else u need to use findOrFail

```
$this->config = Config::findOrFail(1);
```

it will return 404 if config is not find